# CQL - exclude column(s) based on value

Tags: cassandra, cql

In my cassandra DB, I have a table with many columns, majority of them having `NULL` value. Is there projection to return only the columns that contain non-null value? Example:

```
name | birth_date | decease_date |
-----+------------+--------------+
Joe  | 1.1.1920   | 1.2.2005     |
Jane | 1.1.1980   | NULL         |
```

By calling `SELECT ??? FROM users WHERE name = 'Jane'`, I would like to get the following result:

```
name | birth_date |
-----+------------+
Jane | 1.1.1980   |
```

I don't know upfront which columns contain null values, so this needs to be dynamic. Is there a way in CQL to achieve this? Performance is not an issue, the tables are rather small.

EDIT: After doing a bit of research, it seems like there might be some useful features for this in Cassandra 3. Sadly, I need to use it with Cassandra 2...